# File-handling example problems

Tags: c#, file-io, command-line, filestream, streamreader

This is probably something I'm overlooking, but after running my program, I keep returning:

> "ListIT could not find the file"

Here is my code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try {
        int ctr = 0;
        if (args.Length <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Format: ListIT filename");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
                StreamReader t = new StreamReader(f);
                string line;
                while((line = t.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    ctr++;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ctr, line);
                }
                f.Close();
            }
            finally { f.Close(); }
        }
    }
    catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("ListIT could not find the file ", args[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}\n\n", e);
    }
}
```

And here is my input into the command line:

> csc.exe ex47_1.exe [Enter]
>   ex47_1.exe listit ex47_1.cs [Enter]

Any Suggestions? I'm fairly new to C#.

Edt: I've been teaching myself programming over the past 4 years, and this was the first time I used a Sam's Teach Yourself book. I didn't realize how many errors are in all the examples. Thank you for your help, but this taught me not to totally rely on the source to have everything correct.

Comment: Uh... How about the file you specified could not be found in the current directory?

Comment: Instead of your custom error message, change `catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)` to `catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)` and tell us the value of `e`

Comment: Use the Debugger, Luke!

Comment: To further Jonathan's comment, by current directory it's .../Projects/`MyProject`/bin/Debug where `MyProject` is your project.

Comment: Check your working directory.

Comment: @JonathanWood Current directory: C:\Users\...\cSharp files

Comment: @user3101180: By stating what your current directory is and not confirming the obvious question about if the expected file is in *that* directory, my confidence that you understand the basic issue here is extremely low.

Comment: @paqogomez Here you go: 
C:\Users\user_name\cSharp files>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.e
xe ex47_1.exe
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.18408
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

error CS2015: 'c:\Users\user_name\cSharp files\ex47_1.exe' is a binary file instead
        of a text file
error CS1504: Source file 'c:\Users\user_name\cSharp files\ex47_1.exe' could not be
        opened ('Unspecified error ')

Comment: @UweKeim If I were using an IDE, I would have used Debug. I'm using cmd.exe, however, and have never used that debugger.

Comment: @user3101180 So for you it is faster to _not_ use the IDE and instead post a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @UweKeim You could have easily just not have answered my question

Comment: @UweKeim has a point.  With a few print statements you could figure out this problem.  It looks as though you are trying to open `args[0]`, near as I can tell, `args[0]` is `listit`. I think you want to open `args[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how running C# programs from command line, however, if I remember correctly in C++ when starting a program from the command line, the first argument is the name of the program.

I.E.

(Command Line Input)
myProgram.exe myArgFile.txt

Args[0] == "myProgram.exe"
Args[1] == "myArgFile.txt"

Are you meaning to look at Args[1] instead of Args[0]?

UPDATE: What was said above does not apply to C#, however in this instance your code is trying to find file "listit" which is your Args[0]. What I believe you want is your "ex47_1.cs" file which is Args[1]. So change:

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open);
```

to

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: @user3101180, This is the right answer, but for the wrong reason.  Blind, perhaps you should update your answer to reflect that `args[0]` is `listit` and `args[1]` is the path OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to open a file without specifying the path is *always* a tricky thing. You never know whether the current working directory is really what you think it is without explicitly checking, especially when running the application from Visual Studio or using a shortcut.

Soooo... The fact that you don't specify a path name leads me to think you want to use a file from the directoy that the current exe file resides in, so you could use this:

```
string myPathName = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string realFileName = Path.Combine(myPathName, args[0]);
```